# How to allow users to edit their account without providing a password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using Rails 4 and Devise 3.2.4 for authentication.

I'm trying to allow users to update their account (eg: name, email....etc ) without providing password.

I have followed this tutorial -> [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)

After doing what the tutorial said, I am able to to update the user without providing password but when I want to change the "password" itself, I don't need to provide password confirmation and current password.

How do I allow users to change first name, last name without providing password and when changing password, user needs to type password, password confirmation and current password.

Please see below my code.

Thanks.

## ===Update==

My code doesn't seem to work if I have `:validatable` in my `User Model`

## ==

### registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    def update
        account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)

        if account_update_params[:password].blank?
           account_update_params.delete("password")
           account_update_params.delete("password_confirmation")
        end

        @user = User.find(current_user.id)
        if @user.update_attributes(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
           set_flash_message :notice, :updated
           sign_in @user, :bypass => true
           redirect_to @user
        else
            render "edit"
        end

    end

protected

end
```

### application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?



  protected


  def configure_permitted_parameters

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u|
      u.permit(:firstname, :lastname, :password, :password_confirmation )}
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your registration controller by this code

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)

    successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
      @user.update_with_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
    else
      # remove the virtual current_password attribute
      # update_without_password doesn't know how to ignore it
      params[:user].delete(:current_password)
      @user.update_without_password(devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update))
    end

    if successfully_updated
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private

  # check if we need password to update user data
  # ie if password or email was changed
  # extend this as needed
  def needs_password?(user, params)
    user.email != params[:user][:email] ||
      params[:user][:password].present?
  end
end
```

With this code, you will require to put in password when changing password and email and will not require password when changing any other information

Comment: thanks for the answer, it doesn't work, when I tried to update my first-name, it says "Current password can't be blank"

Comment: it should work , as mentioned by the tutorial itself

Comment: I think it has something to do with the :validatable module.

Comment: its related to validations. you can save the user as user.save(validate: false). the drawback of skipping validations is that some critical data(say email) that may be invalid will still be saved.